# How do you implement a binary search for object arrays in a general program?

Tags: java, generics, binary-search, comparable

So, I am in a course to learn java, and I'm learning about sorting, searching, algorithms, and generics. I am trying to recreate a binary search method/class that accepts any type of `Comparable` object (like the ArrayList<*Type*>).

I understand how to do it with `int`s, but I dont really know how to go about it with non-primitive types.
This is what I assume it should roughly look like:

```
public class Objects<T> implements Comparable //I'm not sure about this,
//but I need to call compareTo() to compare the objects?
{
    /**
     * called from other program to find an element index in an array
     */
    public static int binSearchAll(T find, T array[])
    {
        return binarySearch(array, 0, (array.length)-1, find);
    }

    public static int binarySearch(T array[], int lower, int upper, T X)
    //x is the element to find
    {
        if (upper < lower)
            return -1;
        int middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if (array[middle].compareTo(X))
            return middle;
        if (array[middle] < X)
            return binarySearch(a, middle+1, upper, X);
        else
            return binarySearch(a, lower, middle-1, X);
    }
}
```

I tried to figure out how to make this work, but I'm at a loss. In the `int` version, it works, but then it's only for `integer` types and doesn't accept `double` or `string` types as the problem asks.

in the driver class, I want to be able to create a new object and use it like this:

```
String[] str = {"a", "b", "c"};
Objects<String> s = new Objects<String>();
int indexOfB = s.binSearchAll("b", str);
```

or, if it's possible, like this:

```
String[] str = {"a", "b", "c"};
int indexOfB = Object<String>.binSearchAll("b", str);
```

The exact wording of the problem is:

> Create an ObjectBinarySearcher class that can search an array of Comparable objects.
>   Demonstrate the class in a program that searches for a String in an array of String
>   objects.

I'm almost sure I'm overthinking this.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are the problem:

```
if (array[middle].compareTo(X))
...
if (array[middle] < X)
```

... `compareTo` returns an `int` rather than a `boolean`, and you can't use `<` on arbitrary types. I suspect you've realized that much, but I'll just give you a hint: read the [`Comparable.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) documentation. You need to use `compareTo` instead of `<`... read the documentation for the return value to work out what you need to do.

(You probably just want to call `compareTo` once, and then check the result twice. There are three possibilities to consider, as documented...)

Comment: thanks, I wasn't reading the right doc for the Comparable class, and I now have it working. I thought it was similar to the Object.equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need that your template class `T` implements the `Comparable` interface. Your actual code means that only your `Objects` class implement the interface.  You must turn

```
public class Objects<T> implements Comparable {
    //class content...
}
```

Into

```
public class Objects<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    //class content...
}
```

And also, follow the advice from [JonSkeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721110/1065197) about `compareTo` method.

Comment: Thanks, I am just learning, so I didn't realize that was what was happening. I was also confused at why I kept getting an error when I called the compareTo() method and I now understand that it has to be overridden in the class to use it unless the data type already overrides it. I now have it working.

Comment: @user2005078 since you're new here, don't forget to mark the best post as answer by clicking on the check below the rep. If both answers satisfy you, you can post a new answer and accept it.

Comment: that still won't work. it needs to be `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Answer (score 0):

> You need that your template class T implements the Comparable
>   interface. Your actual code means that only your Objects class
>   implement the interface. You must turn
>
> ```
> public class Objects<T> implements Comparable {
>     //class content...
> }
> ```
>
> Into
>
> ```
> public class Objects<T extends Comparable<T>> {
>     //class content...
> }
> ```
>
> [Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza)

And...

> These two lines are the problem:
>   if (array[middle].compareTo(X)) ... if (array[middle] < X) ...
>   compareTo returns an int rather than a boolean, and you can't use < on
>   arbitrary types. I suspect you've realized that much, but I'll just
>   give you a hint: read the Comparable.compareTo documentation. You need
>   to use compareTo instead of <... read the documentation for the return
>   value to work out what you need to do.
>
> (You probably just want to call compareTo once, and then check the
>   result twice. There are three possibilities to consider, as
>   documented...)
>    [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Thanks for the answers. combined, I managed to get the program working.
It now works with:

```
String[] str = {"a", "b", "c"};
Objects<String> s = new Objects<String>();
int indexOfB = s.binSearchAll("b", str);
```